# PayPal IPN notify-validate is returning sandbox login HTML for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

Overview of problem:

I have implemented the IPN listener and I know that PayPal is directing to it (because of a generated text file), the correct parameters are sent through to me in the QueryString however when I append "&cmd=notify-validate" to the query string for the validation to take place and send it to PayPal, I get the following HTML response:

[image].

When I copy and paste that returned HTML into a blank HTML document I see the following: [image]

Initially I thought my session had expired but when I accessed the Sandbox via my browser, I was automatically logged in. I have even tried clicking on the link in my html document to ensure I am logged in and tried processing another test IPN through the simulator in the sandbox but I keep getting this result. I just can't see what I am doing wrong and the sad thing is that it was working correctly about an hour ago :(

My IPN listener code to send and get the validation response:

```
    Dim payPalUrl As String = PayPalPayment.PayPalURL 'This returns https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(payPalUrl), HttpWebRequest)

    'Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim params() As Byte = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength)
    Dim ipnRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(params)
    Dim ipnPost As String = ipnRequest
    ipnRequest &= "&cmd=notify-validate"
    req.ContentLength = ipnRequest.Length

    myUtility.AuditIPN(filename, ipnRequest)

    ''for proxy
    'Dim proxy As New WebProxy(New System.Uri("http://url:port#"))
    'req.Proxy = proxy

    'Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    Dim streamOut As New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
    streamOut.Write(ipnRequest)
    streamOut.Close()

    Dim streamIn As New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim ipnResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
    streamIn.Close()

    'Rest of the code here... not necessary for this problem
```

Posting the payment to PayPal (if needed). NOTE: I build the form and Response.Write() it in a page. This is the form generation:

```
    Dim form As New StringBuilder
    form.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html>")
    form.AppendLine("<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">")
    form.AppendLine("<head runat=""server"">")
    form.AppendLine(String.Format("<title>{0} {1}</title>", "PayPal payment for", ItemName))
    form.AppendLine("<link href=""../css/paypal.css"" rel=""stylesheet"" />")
    form.AppendLine("</head>")
    form.AppendLine("<body>")
    form.AppendLine("<div class=""paypal""></div>")
    form.AppendLine(String.Format("<p>Accessing PayPal to process your payment for the {0}.</p>", ItemName))
    form.AppendLine("<div class=""loading""></div>")
    form.AppendLine("<form id=""myform"" action=""https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"" method=""post"">")
    form.AppendLine("<input type=""hidden"" name=""cmd"" value=""_xclick"">")
    form.AppendLine(String.Format("<input type=""hidden"" name=""business"" value=""{0}"">", BusinessEmail))
    form.AppendLine(String.Format("<input type=""hidden"" name=""item_name"" value=""{0}"">", ItemName))
    form.AppendLine(String.Format("<input type=""hidden"" name=""amount"" value=""{0}"">", Amount))
    form.AppendLine(String.Format("<input type=""hidden"" name=""currency_code"" value=""{0}"">", Currency))
    form.AppendLine(String.Format("<input type=""hidden"" name=""return"" value=""{0}"">", ReturnURL))
    form.AppendLine("<input type=""hidden"" name=""button_subtype"" value=""products"">")
    form.AppendLine("<input type=""hidden"" name=""bn"" value=""HHMRKWQT8NRTW:PP-BuyNowBF_P"">")
    form.AppendLine("<input type=""hidden"" name=""no_note"" value=""0"">")
    form.AppendLine("</form>")
    form.AppendLine("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
    form.AppendLine("    document.forms[""myform""].submit();")
    form.AppendLine("</script>")
    return form.ToString()
```

If I need to post anything else regarding this issue, please let me know as my brain is completely fried at the moment.

Your time and help will greatly be appreciated!

NOTE: Although my code is in VB.NET I develop in C# too, so C# sample code will definitely not be frowned upon!

**Answer:**

If you receive HTML in return, then the notify-validate is not correctly sent through to PayPal. It needs to be &cmd=_notify-validate (with the underscore directly after the cmd key) I must have somehow identically deleted it in my hazy stupor. My IPN listener is now successfully returning VERIFIED :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you receive HTML in return, then the notify-validate is not correctly sent through to PayPal. It needs to be &cmd=_notify-validate (with the underscore directly after the cmd key) I must have somehow accidentally deleted it in my hazy stupor. My IPN listener is now successfully returning VERIFIED :)

Comment: Such a simple mistake but I did this too. Thanks for posting the answer, now I'll be able to sleep this weekend!

Comment: Little late to the game here but its important to note this MUST be the first parameter and you need the & delimeter at the end so that you have &cmd=_notify-validate&